# Restricted basis entry for stepwise linearization

Tags: linear-programming, pyomo, linearization

I am working on a nonlinear function (such as x^2) using bounded stepwise linearization method.
Actually, it requires some restricted conditions, namely restricted basis entry rule. It means: Only two adjacent w_ij are allowed to enter the basis.

i is the index of variable and j is the index of interval.

More explanation on this method can found in:

http://civil.colorado.edu/~balajir/CVEN5393/lectures/chapter-08.pdf

I could not find any clue on how to implement it in pyomo.
I will be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: In the docs see sos2

Comment: when running with cplex solver, pyomo gives an error that the solver does not support sos2.